# Is there a way to have a proper Facebook dialog width on mobile screens?

Tags: facebook, mobile

The width of the request dialogs doesn't display in a proper way on mobile screens (I'm using an ipod touch with safari), the **width is too long and the "Send" button is out of the screen, at right**.

Is there a way to make the dialog display fit the mobile screen real estate?

You can test it on the Facebook official mobile test app: 
http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook

Once you are logged, click on Requests and try to send one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many ways without success until I followed the steps from:

http://www.johnnypez.com/uncategorized/customising-fb-ui-iframe-dialog-dimensions/

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is now broken and I'm having this problem right now.